# Google Maps API v3 - EventListeners `click` and `closeclick` on infowindows conflicting?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-markers, infowindow, event-listener

I am using the events `click` and `closeclick` to set different values with the methods `panTo()` and `setZoom()`.
So when the user clicks on a map marker, it will pan to that marker and zoom in. *This part is working.* Then, when the infowindow is closed I want it to zoom out and pan to the original position (*not working*).
These two events seem to be conflicting in my code, so do I need to make use of `clearListeners` to resolve this conflict? Here is the relevant code:

```
function setInfoWindow(mapRef, mapSettings, mapMarker, markerInfoWindow)
{
    // event listener for infowindow of each map marker, onclick
    google.maps.event.addListener(mapMarker, "click", function()
    {
        markerInfoWindow.open(mapRef, this);
        mapRef.panTo(this.position);
        mapRef.setZoom(3);
    });

    // 
    google.maps.event.addListener(mapMarker, "closeclick", function()
    {
        mapRef.panTo(mapSettings.center);
        mapRef.setZoom(2);
    });

} // end of function setInfoWindow
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is happening because you are not listening for a close event on the infoWindow, you have it set to marker. So simply change the `mapMarker` in your code to `markerInfoWindow`:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(markerInfoWindow, "closeclick", function()
{
    mapRef.panTo(mapSettings.center);
    mapRef.setZoom(2);
});
```

This will fire once the infoWindow is closed: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#InfoWindow Scroll down to Events to see the other events you can add a listener for on the infoWindow.